# awk and escaped characters

Tags: bash, awk

I have got a working snipet:

```
grep 0rang3 /tmp/wifiSpot.txt | awk '/0rang3/{flag=1} flag; /Pairwise/{flag=0}' /tmp/wifiSpot.txt
```

now in place of '0rang3' I would like a variable that is read:

```
read -rp 'what essid ?' ESSID
```

if it's a multiple word essid like 'Orange Airbox-B59C', I need to wrap it like this "${ESSID}" instead of "$ESSID"

when I try

```
grep "${ESSID}" /tmp/wifiSpot.txt | awk '/\"${ESSID}\"/{flag=1} flag; /Pairwise/{flag=0}' /tmp/wifiSpot.txt
```

grep "${ESSID}" ->  works but,

awk '/\"${ESSID}\"/... -> does not work

I tried:

```
'/\"\$\{ESSID\}\"/
```

'/$ESSID/

I cannot find a way to have it working

Any idea folks? thanx in advance.

Comment: Take a look at awk's option `-v`.

Comment: wrt `grep 0rang3 /tmp/wifiSpot.txt | awk '/0rang3/` - which lines from the grep output do you expect to NOT match the same regexp in awk? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output if you'd like help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the grep part makes no sense in your pipe chain, in the awk command, you didn't read anything that you passed to the pipe. You can remove it.

What you need is:

```
awk -v pat="$ESSID" '$0~pat{flag=1}flag; /Pairwise/{flag=0}' yourFile
```